# Removing the suffix in a folder name using bash

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I have the following code that renames by removing digits at the start of a folder name but what I need is something that will remove letters and numbers from the end.

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in "$@"; do
    fpath="${f%/*}"
    fname="${f##*/}"
    mv "$f" "$fpath"/"${fname/#+([[:digit:]])_/}"
```

**Example**

```
Input - 001_AA_0001_AG1_V1_CD

Output - 001_AA_0001
```

Comment: So remove anything after `_<digits>` ?

Comment: yes, your example data is ambiguous. Is the rule really delete everything after the 3rd '_' char? Or is it delete everything after 4 digits? OR ?? Have you looked at all of your folders and will this example solve all cases? Consider updating your Q to eliminate questions about the scope of your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I want to delete anything after the 3rd '_' char.  I'm running the bash script as part of an Automator workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use a Bash Parameter Expansion?
Here is a single line `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]*\).*/\1/' $filename
```

To rename the file:

```
mv $filename $(sed 's/\([0-9]*_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]*\).*/\1/' $filename)
```

Note that this requires you to be inside the directory where the file is located.

***FOR AUTOMATOR:***

```
for filename in "$@"
do
    mv "$filename" $(sed 's/\([0-9]*_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]*\).*/\1/' $filename)
done
```

1. Choose `Get Selected Finder Items` as the first step.
2. Then `Run Shell Script`
3. Set `Pass input:` to `as arguments`
4. Set the shell script to that above
5. And voilà!

Comment: Is it possible to run that inside Automator?  The action runs by does nothing?

Comment: It does nothing because it is merely a textual representation. See my edit. Also do you mean OS X Automator? Otherwise I don't know what you mean by Automator. And I don't really know Automator that well. And I'm positive whatever you want to do, you can do it using exclusively shell script just as well.

Comment: Thank you henrikgiesel for the reply.  Yes - Automator in OSX.  I'm trying to run the rename as part of a larger workflow.  Is there any way to tell the SED script to run on what's been selected?

Comment: See my answer for more details

Comment: That seems to move my folders to the desktop and rename them by using the selected folder name.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand this behavior. Always to the Desktop? You sure you did everything as I told you?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem but not using bash.  Instead I found a set of pre built Automator actions.  The Text Automator Action Pack can be used to remove characters from the start or end of a string.  I used this to rename my folders.

http://www.automatedworkflows.com/products/apps/automator-actions-for-mac-os-x-10-610-7-snow-leopard-lion/